Full Node and Pool ZMQ Error
i'm new into the BitcoinCore und started a FullNode. The Node is running well on Debian12 VPS.
I'm also setup a Mining Pool and get some Problems ....
(Username and Passwort i changed already so don't worry)
Everytime i started the Pool i got:
ZMQ Unable to connect, Retrying

i can't figure out whats my fault :(
Here the bitcoin.conf of my Node:
listen=1
upnp=0
txindex=1
maxconnections=40
server=1
rpcthreads=4
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxx
#rpcauth=
rpcauth=bitcoin:xxx
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpctimeout=30
txconfirmtarget=6
mempoolexpiry=72
maxmempool=300
maxorphantx=100
debug=rpc
logips=1
limitfreerelay=10
minrelaytxfee=0.0001
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333
[main]
rpcbind=185.218.x.x
[test]
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
[regtest]
rpcbind=0.0.0.0

thats the pool.env of my Pool:
BITCOIN_RPC_URL=http://185.218.x.x
BITCOIN_RPC_USER=xxx
BITCOIN_RPC_PASSWORD=xxx
BITCOIN_RPC_PORT=18332
BITCOIN_RPC_TIMEOUT=10000
BITCOIN_ZMQ_HOST="tcp://185.218.x.x:28332"

API_PORT=3334
STRATUM_PORT=3333

#optional telegram bot
#TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN=

#optional discord bot
#DISCORD_BOT_CLIENTID=
#DISCORD_BOT_GUILD_ID=
#DISCORD_BOT_CHANNEL_ID=

#optional
#DEV_FEE_ADDRESS=
# mainnet | testnet
NETWORK=mainnet

API_SECURE=false

ENABLE_SOLO=true
ENABLE_PROXY=false

BRAIINS_ACCESS_TOKEN=

PROXY_PORT=3333

the IP 185.218.x.x is the IP of the Node.
Can someone please help me to figure out where my mistake is?
Thanks a lot

When you specify the ZMQ bind, you are also specifying the address it will listen on. This means that if your machine has multiple IP addresses. only when it is reached through the specified IP address will the specified port be open.
You specified the ZMQ should bind on the localhost address 127.0.0.1. However, your pool configuration is trying to reach it via a different IP address of 185.218.x.x. As ZMQ is bound to a 127.0.0.1, it cannot respond to anything received on 185.218.x.x.
You can change this by binding to 185.218.x.x, or by binding to all IPs by using 0.0.0.0.

thats works for me ... thank you
